# Calculating the area of a shape

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, area

Consider square $1\times 1$ that has been crossed by two pairs of lines [image]

Knowing that area of the red figure is equal $\frac{1}{m}$ and $m,n\in \mathbb{N_+}$:

a) calculate $n$ if $m=1985$

b) calculate set of all possible values of $m\in \mathbb {N}$ such that $m>1985$, for which a) is solvable.

---

Obviously first I tried to calculate function $f(n)$ that calculates the area of the red rhombus.

I introduced two new variables - $\alpha$ (see image) and $a$ - length of the rhombus' side, and wrote following equations:
$$
\tan\alpha =\frac{1-\frac{1}{n}}{1}=\frac{n-1}{n}
$$
and:
$$
\cos\alpha =\frac{a}{\frac{1}{n}}=an
$$

The red square is a rhombus so its area is:
$$
f(n)=a^2 \sin (180-2\alpha)=a^2 sin(2\alpha)=(\frac{\cos\alpha}{n})^2 \cdot 2\sin \alpha \cos \alpha=2\frac{\cos ^3 \alpha \sin \alpha}{n^2}
$$

Unfortunately I don't know how to proceed further, so I'm asking for Your assisstance.

Comment: Hint: sine is adjacent over hypotenuse, and you can compute each of these in terms of $n$. Similar for cosine. Also, $KLMN$ is a square because the diagram has a 90-degree rotational symmetry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Hint: $\alpha+\beta=90^\circ$,
hence $KLMN$ is a square.

> \begin{align} n(m) &= \tfrac12+\tfrac12\sqrt{2m-1},\\ n(1985)&=32\end{align}

Comment: Oh, that simplifies this a lot. Thank you, I managed to achieve the same answer as yours.